# VB Thread Timer Update UI

Tags: vb.net, timer

I made a small program that allows for individual timer countdowns for each button clicked. (e.g. clicking on button 1 will start a countdown for button 1 whilst updating the text on the button itself to reflect the time remaining.)

My worry now is that I'm not sure how well my program would work in the long run. Here's a snippet of the code.

```
 Private Sub depBtn_Clicked(sender As Button, e As EventArgs)
    If sender.BackColor = Color.Green Then
        Dim depRow() As Data.DataRow
        Dim id As String = sender.Name
        depRow = DepartmentDataSet.Departments.Select("ID Like '" & id & "'")          
        sender.BackColor = Color.Red

        Dim timerBtn As New DepartmentTimer(sender, depRow(0)("Duration"), depRow(0)("ID"))

        Dim TimerDelegate As New System.Threading.TimerCallback(AddressOf TimerTask)
        Dim TimerItem As New System.Threading.Timer(TimerDelegate, timerBtn, 0, 1000)
        timerBtn.timerRef = TimerItem
    End If
End Sub

Private Delegate Sub TimerTaskDelegate(ByVal obj As Object)

Private Sub TimerTask(ByVal obj As Object)
    If Me.InvokeRequired() Then
        Me.Invoke(New TimerTaskDelegate(AddressOf TimerTask), obj)
    Else
        Dim depTimer As DepartmentTimer = DirectCast(obj, DepartmentTimer)
        depTimer.countDown()

        If depTimer.duration = -1 Then
            depTimer.finish()
            depTimer.timerRef.Dispose()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I have read and also experienced that if I were to update on the UI thread directly from the timer callback the whole program would crash. So I ended up using a delegate in accordance to here http://tech.xster.net/tips/invoke-ui-changes-across-threads-on-vb-net/.

Is this a proper way of doing it or am I doing anything redundant/inefficient?
Also when I dispose of the Timer object. How would I go about cleaning up the DepartmentTimer class instance (timerBtn)? The button can be activated again once the timer runs out so I'm afraid that the instances would build up if I don't take care of them properly.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not actually doing anything with the Timer except immediately Invoking back to the main UI thread, you might as well just use **one** System.Windows.Forms.Timer and update them all in the same handler.

Something like:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private timers As New List(Of DepartmentTimer)
    Private WithEvents Tmr As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Tmr.Interval = 1000
        Tmr.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub depBtn_Clicked(sender As Button, e As EventArgs)
        If sender.BackColor = Color.Green Then
            Dim depRow() As Data.DataRow
            Dim id As String = sender.Name
            depRow = DepartmentDataSet.Departments.Select("ID Like '" & id & "'")
            sender.BackColor = Color.Red

            timers.Add(New DepartmentTimer(sender, depRow(0)("Duration"), depRow(0)("ID")))
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Tmr_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Tmr.Tick
        For i As Integer = timers.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            Dim depTimer As DepartmentTimer = timers(i)
            depTimer.countDown()

            If depTimer.duration = -1 Then
                depTimer.finish()
                timers.RemoveAt(i)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Sorry bout this but would that mean that all the buttons would be counting down at same intervals? What if I clicked on the buttons at different times?

Comment: No.  They all update once per second, but have their own durations stored in each DepartmentTimer instance.  Also, I fixed the declaration of "timers" in my example.  Try it out and see if it works.  Just comment out your code so you can revert back.